# Creating folders automatically on Member login

Tags: plone, member, zope

I'm using the Plone Member Folders feature, where a folder of certain member is created when member is logging in.

How to add some folders to be created at login? Not only folder with name of member, but some folders inside too?

Comment: Please use separate posts for separate questions; it makes it much easier to upvote correct answers that way.

Comment: I've removed the second question, you can repost that as a separate post (see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11843427/revisions for the old revisions of this post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `notifyMemberAreaCreated` skin method to add extra content in a newly-created member folder. The script will be called in the context of this new folder.

The reason that this has to be a skin script, and not a view or an event handler, is because this part of Plone stems from an older feature in the CMF, one that hasn't been updated to more modern API standards yet.

Here's an example `notifyMemberAreaCreated.py` python skin script:

```
## Script (Python) "notifyMemberAreaCreated"
##bind container=container
##bind context=context
##bind namespace=
##bind script=script
##bind subpath=traverse_subpath
##parameters=
##title=Modify new member area
##

context.invokeFactory('Folder',id='subfolder')
context.subfolder.setTitle('Your new subfolder')
context.reindexObject()
```

You may have to give this script the `Manager` proxy role. If you define this skin script on the filesystem, in your custom skin layer, add a `.metadata` file (named `notifyMemberAreaCreated.py.metadata`) to set this proxy role:

```
[default]
proxy=Manager
```

Comment: Thank you, everything works. But how to accept two posts now? :D

Comment: I've followed this post and made the same, but doesn't work.
I've created the file notifyMemberAreaCreated.py and the file notifyMemberAreaCreated.py.metadata in the folder:
/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.PlonePAS-4.0.13-py2.7.egg/Products/PlonePAS/tools/, but when an user login for the first time the folder name "Your new subfolder" doesn't exists.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: You create the script in the skin layer of your *own* theme product; the `/tools` directory in that egg is *not* a skin layer and the script is not going to be found.

Answer (score 2):

In Plumi (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumi.app) you can see how it is done. A folder structure which is initially in the profile of plumi.app is created on installation in a so called default_member_area. In notifyMemberAreaCreated.py the default_member_area is copied into the new member folder.

Comment: Very thank you that was very useful post. Some greps and everything is clear :)